# SQL table data not appearing on page

Tags: php, sql

simple one, I am having difficulty with my sql data not showing on webpage using php. I have a seperate page which connects to the DB as per. However using simple connection php scripting is not displaying the results...

```
<?php
include("header.php");
include("connect.php");
?>



<?php

    $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY id ASC");

    $id = 'id';
    $username = 'username';
    $useremail = 'useremail';
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

    echo 'Name: ' . $rows[$id] . '<br />' . 'Username: ' . $rows[$useremail];

    ?>
```

I have even tried this but still nothing...

```
<?php

    include 'includes/connect.php';


    $query = "SELECT * FROM members";

    $result = mysqli_query ($query);

    while($person = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo "<h1>" . $person['useremail'] . "</h1>";

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Are there any errors?  Are you certain you are getting any records in your recordset?  Have you tried $rows['id'] instead of $rows[$id]?  Do you have errors on?  Tell us what you have tried.

Comment: @Steve that is the odd thing...no errors...

Comment: Do you have error display turned on?

Comment: Yeah, well its a test page that's live. I changed the suggested by Steve but still nothing showing. It is bizarre...

Comment: Does it echo if you put something before all the SQL stuff?  Does it echo if you just try  echo 'name';  after the SQL?    Strip it back to bare bones and trouble shoot.

Comment: I have taken out the SQL and left only the SELECT I have adjusted it numerous ways but getting nothing...

Comment: whats in your header.php and connect.php?

Comment: Hi Migg header just contains the topbar of my website (which is called in and works) which incidentally loads the users first and last names in that very top bar. The Connect.php is the connection to the database. I can show you the script?

Comment: You can have errors, even if they don't display on-screen as a message (notice/warning/etc.).  Have you checked the return values of `mysqli_query()` (`$sql`/`$result`) and `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`(`$rows`/`$person`) contain the values you expect?  Using `var_dump()` is helpful trying to identify variable values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check you have written all connection variables correctly in `connect.php`. You are using `$rows[$id]` which is not problem because you have defined variable `$id='id'`. But problem is you are not using loop. If you will print

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo $rows[$id];
```

it will just give one record;
Please try with following

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$db='mydata';//change above four variable as per your setting or write down in connect.php
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($con,$db);
$id = 'id';
$username = 'username';
$useremail = 'useremail';
$q="SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY id ASC";
$r=mysqli_query($con,$q);
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
    echo "Name :".$rows[$username]."<br />"."useremail :".$useremail."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: this was interesting because this worked....however it mimics the data that is in connect.php

Comment: This is what is in my connect.php (obv mine has username and password)

<?php

 // MySQL connect information.
 $c_username = "";
 $c_password = "";
 $c_host = "localhost";
 $c_database = "project";

 // Connect.
 $connection = mysqli_connect($c_host, $c_username, $c_password)
 or die ("It seems this site's database isn't responding.");

 mysqli_select_db($connection, $c_database)
 or die ("It seems this site's database isn't responding.");
?>

Comment: just remove or make comment four variables $host,$user,$pass,$db and mysqli_select_db line in the working file bcause already added in connect.php, please check the path of connect.php. try to include the file by giving absolute path rather than relative path. write die(mysqli_error()) instead of die ("It seems this site's database isn't responding.") to check error

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir - Another quick question - I have a coumn which is also in members table which has most likes against the user...how do I sort against that instead of ASC?

Comment: Ignore that All figured out now!